# GAE blobstore: can't upload file using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, jersey, blobstore

i'm trying to upload images to the Blobstore using GAE + Jersey framework (Java).

I call this method to get a valid URL to upload my image:

```
@GET
@Path("/urlToUpload")
public Response getUrlToUploadImage(){

    String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/image/upload");

    return Response.ok(url).build();
}
```

The callback method is:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadImage(@Context HttpServletRequest req){

    String token = req.getParameter("userToken");
    String label = req.getParameter("label");

    User user = null;

    if(token == null || (user = ofy().load().type(User.class).filter("token", token).first().now()) == null)
        return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();

    Image image = new Image();
    image.key = this.loadImage(req);
    image.label = label;
    image.user = Ref.create(user);

    ofy().save().entity(image).now();

    return Response.ok(image.key).build();
}
```

and the loadImage() method is:

```
private String loadImage(HttpServletRequest req){
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobFields = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);

    BlobKey blobKey = null;

    List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobFields.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue();
    if (blobKeys != null && !blobKeys.isEmpty()) blobKey = blobKeys.get(0);

    return blobKey.getKeyString();
}
```

So when i make a request like **http://xxxx.appspot.com/image/urlToUpload** i get back an URL like this one:

```
http://xxxx.appspot.com/_ah/upload/?token=bkd0ZmZKUkVQYVNXQmh0OGFmUkxaUHlUc0xpT1pUSDdyOFVmMGtLUDlKQzVjdXplUmluNmcxRHVNb1pYc3M4aTMrQ3loa2NHaklHcVBtL2NnMXAxOVdWUndGdExibDdzN2JJU1k3QmFoWFVYSVdnTUt5SkRJdz0/AMmfu6YyFqr8i0pf5u5LiM1tzu79TZwztQgw_DWa1e3l7bWly99Ui6y9prF29NHU7DZg8RFZKDUuvCE-vWqjGr_oQTV0RM8T3AG2Tk9iVayuYl0uCRTmNt-RGS5B9bs_cKgDnib-8AxT/ALBNUaYAAAAAUraynFI4WVGvSMHU_Uz8JptJ5M36uGDl/
```

so i make a POST request using that URL sending a form-data with these parameters:

**userToken** : .......

**label** : test label for the image

**image** : the image (file)

and i get back this error message:

> Error: Server Error
>
> The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
>   Please retry your last submission.
>
> If the problem persists, please contact the person responsible for the
>   application you're using, or, if you are that person, report your
>   problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

but i can't see the server error.

Where i'm wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! It would be awesome to have more of the logs here. In the absence of them, many different things might contribute to an internal server error.